# How to Create A Unique URL for each product enquiry form for Google Analytics Tracking

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, contact-form-7

I have a WooCommerce website. The products are of high value and digital downloads. So there are three buttons on the product page which say, 
1. Enquiry.
2. Request A Discount.
3. Request A Sample.

I have added those buttons via the child theme's function.php file.
I have included the code below.

I have generated an enquiry-form page and have pasted the contact form shortcode in it. I have added Contact Form 7's Dynamic Text Extension, which gives me the referrer URL without any issues, and I can track which product the person is requesting the sample for.

I now want to add a product ID to the URL i.e. to /enquiry-form/?productID or something similar, so every product can be tracked in Google Analytics as well.

Can you please tell me how I can do this? 
I am very new to PHP and WordPress.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_extra_button_on_product_page', 30 );

function my_extra_button_on_product_page() {
  global $product;
  echo '<a href="https://mywebsite.com/sample-form/" class="sample-button">Request A Sample</a><br><br>';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_extra_button_on_product_page2', 30 );

function my_extra_button_on_product_page2() {
  global $product;
  echo '<a href="https://mywebsite.com/enquiry-form/" class="enquiry-button">Enquiry</a><br><br>';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_extra_button_on_product_page3', 30 );

function my_extra_button_on_product_page3() {
  global $product;
  echo '<a href="https://mywebsite.com/discount-form/" class="discount-button">Request A Discount</a><br><br>';
}
```

After putting the var_dump($product); here is what is shown on the product page:

```
object(WC_Product_Variable)#1912 (15) { ["children":protected]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(5338) [1]=> int(5339) } ["visible_children":protected]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(5338) [1]=> int(5339) } ["variation_attributes":protected]=> array(1) { ["License"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(11) "Single User" [1]=> string(15) "Enterprise User" } } ["object_type":protected]=> string(7) "product" ["post_type":protected]=> string(7) "product" ["cache_group":protected]=> string(8) "products" ["data":protected]=> array(50) { ["name"]=> string(123) “product title is here” ["slug"]=> string(120) “product-title-is-here” ["date_created"]=> object(WC_DateTime)#1938 (4) { ["utc_offset":protected]=> int(0) ["date"]=> string(26) "2019-08-08 10:24:51.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(1) ["timezone"]=> string(6) "+00:00" } ["date_modified"]=> object(WC_DateTime)#1936 (4) { ["utc_offset":protected]=> int(0) ["date"]=> string(26) "2019-08-17 06:22:36.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(1) ["timezone"]=> string(6) "+00:00" } ["status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["featured"]=> bool(false) ["catalog_visibility"]=> string(7) "visible" ["description"]=> string(3961) “product Description goes here” ["short_description"]=> string(0) "" ["sku"]=> string(0) "" ["price"]=> string(4) "3900" ["regular_price"]=> string(0) "" ["sale_price"]=> string(0) "" ["date_on_sale_from"]=> NULL ["date_on_sale_to"]=> NULL ["total_sales"]=> int(0) ["tax_status"]=> string(7) "taxable" ["tax_class"]=> string(0) "" ["manage_stock"]=> bool(false) ["stock_quantity"]=> NULL ["stock_status"]=> string(7) "instock" ["backorders"]=> string(2) "no" ["low_stock_amount"]=> string(0) "" ["sold_individually"]=> bool(false) ["weight"]=> string(0) "" ["length"]=> string(0) "" ["width"]=> string(0) "" ["height"]=> string(0) "" ["upsell_ids"]=> array(0) { } ["cross_sell_ids"]=> array(0) { } ["parent_id"]=> int(0) ["reviews_allowed"]=> bool(true) ["purchase_note"]=> string(0) "" ["attributes"]=> array(1) { ["license"]=> object(WC_Product_Attribute)#1932 (1) { ["data":protected]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> int(0) ["name"]=> string(7) "License" ["options"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(11) "Single User" [1]=> string(15) "Enterprise User" } ["position"]=> int(0) ["visible"]=> bool(true) ["variation"]=> bool(true) } } } ["default_attributes"]=> array(0) { } ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["virtual"]=> bool(false) ["downloadable"]=> bool(false) ["category_ids"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(20) } ["tag_ids"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(22) [1]=> int(21) } ["shipping_class_id"]=> int(0) ["downloads"]=> array(0) { } ["image_id"]=> string(0) "" ["gallery_image_ids"]=> array(0) { } ["download_limit"]=> int(-1) ["download_expiry"]=> int(-1) ["rating_counts"]=> array(0) { } ["average_rating"]=> string(1) "0" ["review_count"]=> int(0) } ["supports":protected]=> array(0) { } ["id":protected]=> int(5337) ["changes":protected]=> array(0) { } ["object_read":protected]=> bool(true) ["extra_data":protected]=> array(0) { } ["default_data":protected]=> array(50) { ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["slug"]=> string(0) "" ["date_created"]=> NULL ["date_modified"]=> NULL ["status"]=> bool(false) ["featured"]=> bool(false) ["catalog_visibility"]=> string(7) "visible" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["short_description"]=> string(0) "" ["sku"]=> string(0) "" ["price"]=> string(0) "" ["regular_price"]=> string(0) "" ["sale_price"]=> string(0) "" ["date_on_sale_from"]=> NULL ["date_on_sale_to"]=> NULL ["total_sales"]=> string(1) "0" ["tax_status"]=> string(7) "taxable" ["tax_class"]=> string(0) "" ["manage_stock"]=> bool(false) ["stock_quantity"]=> NULL ["stock_status"]=> string(7) "instock" ["backorders"]=> string(2) "no" ["low_stock_amount"]=> string(0) "" ["sold_individually"]=> bool(false) ["weight"]=> string(0) "" ["length"]=> string(0) "" ["width"]=> string(0) "" ["height"]=> string(0) "" ["upsell_ids"]=> array(0) { } ["cross_sell_ids"]=> array(0) { } ["parent_id"]=> int(0) ["reviews_allowed"]=> bool(true) ["purchase_note"]=> string(0) "" ["attributes"]=> array(0) { } ["default_attributes"]=> array(0) { } ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["virtual"]=> bool(false) ["downloadable"]=> bool(false) ["category_ids"]=> array(0) { } ["tag_ids"]=> array(0) { } ["shipping_class_id"]=> int(0) ["downloads"]=> array(0) { } ["image_id"]=> string(0) "" ["gallery_image_ids"]=> array(0) { } ["download_limit"]=> int(-1) ["download_expiry"]=> int(-1) ["rating_counts"]=> array(0) { } ["average_rating"]=> int(0) ["review_count"]=> int(0) } ["data_store":protected]=> object(WC_Data_Store)#1939 (4) { ["instance":"WC_Data_Store":private]=> object(WC_Product_Variable_Data_Store_CPT)#1934 (7) { ["prices_array":protected]=> array(2) { ["version"]=> string(10) "1566022956" ["f9e544f77b7eac7add281ef28ca5559f"]=> array(3) { ["price"]=> array(2) { [5338]=> string(7) "3900.00" [5339]=> string(7) "5900.00" } ["regular_price"]=> array(2) { [5338]=> string(7) "3900.00" [5339]=> string(7) "5900.00" } ["sale_price"]=> array(2) { [5338]=> string(7) "3900.00" [5339]=> string(7) "5900.00" } } } ["internal_meta_keys":protected]=> array(42) { [0]=> string(11) "_visibility" [1]=> string(4) "_sku" [2]=> string(6) "_price" [3]=> string(14) "_regular_price" [4]=> string(11) "_sale_price" [5]=> string(22) "_sale_price_dates_from" [6]=> string(20) "_sale_price_dates_to" [7]=> string(11) "total_sales" [8]=> string(11) "_tax_status" [9]=> string(10) "_tax_class" [10]=> string(13) "_manage_stock" [11]=> string(6) "_stock" [12]=> string(13) "_stock_status" [13]=> string(11) "_backorders" [14]=> string(17) "_low_stock_amount" [15]=> string(18) "_sold_individually" [16]=> string(7) "_weight" [17]=> string(7) "_length" [18]=> string(6) "_width" [19]=> string(7) "_height" [20]=> string(11) "_upsell_ids" [21]=> string(14) "_crosssell_ids" [22]=> string(14) "_purchase_note" [23]=> string(19) "_default_attributes" [24]=> string(19) "_product_attributes" [25]=> string(8) "_virtual" [26]=> string(13) "_downloadable" [27]=> string(15) "_download_limit" [28]=> string(16) "_download_expiry" [29]=> string(9) "_featured" [30]=> string(19) "_downloadable_files" [31]=> string(16) "_wc_rating_count" [32]=> string(18) "_wc_average_rating" [33]=> string(16) "_wc_review_count" [34]=> string(22) "_variation_description" [35]=> string(13) "_thumbnail_id" [36]=> string(11) "_file_paths" [37]=> string(22) "_product_image_gallery" [38]=> string(16) "_product_version" [39]=> string(12) "_wp_old_slug" [40]=> string(10) "_edit_last" [41]=> string(10) "_edit_lock" } ["must_exist_meta_keys":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "_tax_class" } ["extra_data_saved":protected]=> bool(false) ["updated_props":protected]=> array(0) { } ["meta_type":protected]=> string(4) "post" ["object_id_field_for_meta":protected]=> string(0) "" } ["stores":"WC_Data_Store":private]=> array(20) { ["coupon"]=> string(24) "WC_Coupon_Data_Store_CPT" ["customer"]=> string(22) "WC_Customer_Data_Store" ["customer-download"]=> string(31) "WC_Customer_Download_Data_Store" ["customer-download-log"]=> string(35) "WC_Customer_Download_Log_Data_Store" ["customer-session"]=> string(30) "WC_Customer_Data_Store_Session" ["order"]=> string(23) "WC_Order_Data_Store_CPT" ["order-refund"]=> string(30) "WC_Order_Refund_Data_Store_CPT" ["order-item"]=> string(24) "WC_Order_Item_Data_Store" ["order-item-coupon"]=> string(31) "WC_Order_Item_Coupon_Data_Store" ["order-item-fee"]=> string(28) "WC_Order_Item_Fee_Data_Store" ["order-item-product"]=> string(32) "WC_Order_Item_Product_Data_Store" ["order-item-shipping"]=> string(33) "WC_Order_Item_Shipping_Data_Store" ["order-item-tax"]=> string(28) "WC_Order_Item_Tax_Data_Store" ["payment-token"]=> string(27) "WC_Payment_Token_Data_Store" ["product"]=> string(25) "WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT" ["product-grouped"]=> string(33) "WC_Product_Grouped_Data_Store_CPT" ["product-variable"]=> string(34) "WC_Product_Variable_Data_Store_CPT" ["product-variation"]=> string(35) "WC_Product_Variation_Data_Store_CPT" ["shipping-zone"]=> string(27) "WC_Shipping_Zone_Data_Store" ["webhook"]=> string(21) "WC_Webhook_Data_Store" } ["current_class_name":"WC_Data_Store":private]=> string(34) "WC_Product_Variable_Data_Store_CPT" ["object_type":"WC_Data_Store":private]=> string(16) "product-variable" } ["meta_data":protected]=> NULL }
```

Included the code in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ftdamuz9/
as well.

Comment: try to put this code `var_dump($product);` in one of the function (after the line `global $product;`) to let us know the fields of the product object.

Comment: I will put the code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add `?ProductID=id` to your url, you have to modify WP functions in something like that:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_extra_button_on_product_page', 30 );

function my_extra_button_on_product_page() {
  global $product;
  echo '<a href="https://mywebsite.com/sample-form/?ProductID=' . $product->get_id() . '" class="sample-button">Request A Sample</a><br><br>';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_extra_button_on_product_page2', 30 );

function my_extra_button_on_product_page2() {
  global $product;
  echo '<a href="https://mywebsite.com/enquiry-form/?ProductID=' . $product->get_id() . '" class="enquiry-button">Enquiry</a><br><br>';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_extra_button_on_product_page3', 30 );

function my_extra_button_on_product_page3() {
  global $product;
  echo '<a href="https://mywebsite.com/discount-form/?ProductID=' . $product->get_id() . '" class="discount-button">Request A Discount</a><br><br>';
}
```

`$product->get_id()` is the Woocommerce `WC_Data` method to get the ID from the product object.